# Java SSH change password on login

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

```
private String user = "root",
            newPassword = "test123";

private int port = 22;

public SSHConnection(String host, String password) {
     try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.connect();

        out.write(password.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.write(newPassword.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.write(newPassword.getBytes());
        out.flush();

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am asked to change my password on the first time I log in on the server. I am trying to do it with JSch, but I'm not sure how can I accomplish this. As far as I understand I can't use any commands as I'm forced to change password before doing anything, so I can't use

```
 (echo old_password; echo new_password; echo new_password) | passwd username
```

Comment: `passwd` gets its input from the tty, not from stdin.

Comment: What kind of change password prompt is that? Is it some tool, like `passwd`? Or is it a built-in SSH "change password" request?

Comment: It is something you get just after you enter your current login details.
"You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)" and you are asked to enter "(current) UNIX password" and than repeat new password twice

Comment: That does not answer my question. If you want to implement something, you need to know against what protocol you implement it. We cannot guess for yourself. Though from the prompt text, I'd assume it's `passwd`. And as @EJP commented, the `passwd` needs TTY. And it's questionable, what happens when you use `exec` channel. Did you try `exec` channel and/or TTY-less session in GUI SSH client first, to see if you still get the prompt? There are far to many questions that needs an answer, before we can show you some solution.

Comment: Thanks for help managed to make it work by adding channel.setPty(true); and adding "\n" to out.write((password + "\n").getBytes());

Comment: Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by calling channel.setPty(true);

```
private String user = "root",
            newPassword = "test123";

private int port = 22;

public SSHConnection(String host, String password) {
     try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();

        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.setPty(true);
        channel.connect();

        out.write((password + "\n").getBytes());
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        out.write((newPassword + "\n").getBytes());
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        out.write((newPassword + "\n").getBytes());
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I added sleeps before each input for consistency, normally you would want to wait for output before entering each password, but for my uses this will do.

Comment: Would you mind explicitly stating in the answer that you resolved this by calling `setPty`?

Answer (score 0):

For me works running the next command in one command line, without using Thread.sleep

```
echo -e \"new-password\nnew-password\" | passwd user-linux
```